# wsmethodinvocationRef undeclared identifier error for web service

Tags: objective-c, web-services

why undeclared identifier error comes when calling web service using wsmethodInvocationref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This WSMethodInvocationRef does not support in iOS, it only for OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Some more detail on how you "used WSMethodInvocationRef" would be helpful.

Have you included the headers as described in the [Web Services Core reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/WebServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

- WSMethodInvocation.h
- WSProtocolHandler.h
- WSTypes.h